# how to solve this differential equation hmm

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm struggling. Any tips?

$$(x-x^3)y' + (-x^2-1)y-(3x^3)=0$$

well wolfram alpha tells me that after

$$y'+\frac{(x^2+1)y}{x(x^2-1)} = -\frac{3x^2}{x^2-1}$$

I need to add special const $u(x)$ in order to integrate both sides of the equation. the question is how to avoid that? Any ways to solve this much easier? Thanks in advance.

Comment: your deduction still isn't right, maybe there is still a typo in your equation. It's either $(-x^2 - 1)y$ in the first equation, or $\frac{(x^2 + 1)y}{x^3(x^2 - 1)}$ in the second equation.

Comment: yes, you're right. edited

Comment: yea, but I actually asked if there were any ways to solve this not using integrating factor.

Comment: any thoughts are highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not integrating factor?

Comment: tough, I haven't used it at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, no integrating factor and hints.

Solve the homogeneous equation.

$$y' = -\dfrac{(x^2+1)y}{x(x^2-1)}$$

This yields (after a partial fraction expansion of the RHS):

$$\dfrac{dy}{y} = \left(\dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{x+1} - \dfrac{1}{x-1}\right)~ dx$$

Integrate both sides and arrive at:

$$y_h = \dfrac{c x}{1-x^2}$$

Next, solve for the particular solution. Look at the RHS, guess at the particular solution and then solve for the constant.

You should end up with:

$$y = \dfrac{c x}{1-x^2} + \dfrac{3 x^3}{2(1- x^2)}$$

Comment: OK, got it, I'll try. thanks a lot.

Comment: @depay12: You are very welcome, happy to help! Also, once you got your hands around this approach, you should follow the Integrating Factor approach and see if you do that too. Regards

Comment: Nice work! But needs a TU as well as your "Thank U"! +1